NTP Sync between Windows and Ubuntu
I'm configuring time synchronization between a Windows PC and an Ubuntu NTP server for a long time now and I wanted to ask for some help. Here's my setup and what I've tried so far:
Setup:
Ubuntu PC:

IP Address: 192.168.0.100
NTP Server: ntpd running and synchronized with multiple servers.
Firewall (UFW): Disabled

Windows PC:

IP Address: 192.168.0.99
Windows Time service (w32time): Running
Firewall: Added rule to allow UDP traffic on port 123

Steps Taken:
Ubuntu NTP Configuration:
Added the following lines to /etc/ntp.conf:
restrict 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 nomodify notrap
server 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst

Restarted NTP service: (sudo systemctl restart ntp). Verified NTP status (ntpq -p) shows synchronization with upstream servers.
Windows Configuration:
Added firewall rule to allow NTP traffic:
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Allow NTP" protocol=udp dir=in localport=123 
action=allow

Configured NTP server:
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"192.168.0.100" /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:YES /update

Restarted Windows Time service:
net stop w32time
net start w32time

Resynchronization:
w32tm /resync

Issue:
Despite these configurations, the Windows PC continues to use the local CMOS clock as the time source. The output of w32tm /query /status shows:
Source: Local CMOS Clock
ReferenceID: 0x4C4F434C (LOCL)
Stratum: 1

Running w32tm /stripchart /computer:192.168.0.100 /samples:5 /dataonly results in timeout errors:
Tracking 192.168.0.100 [192.168.0.100:123].
Collecting 5 samples.
The current time is 19/08/2024 14:57:27.
14:57:27, +1956.0418399s
14:57:29, +1956.0418009s
14:57:31, +1956.0417711s
14:57:33, +1956.0417003s
14:57:35, +1956.0416871s

...
Additional Information:

I can ping the Ubuntu PC from the Windows PC without any issues.
The Ubuntu NTP server is synchronized with its upstream servers.
On Ubuntu, sudo iptables -L INPUT -v -n returns the default policy is ACCEPT.
Using a second Windows PC on a different network (10.221.xx.xx), I am able to sync successfully, but not using the 192.168.0.x network.

Why is the Windows PC not syncing with the Ubuntu NTP server and continues to use the local CMOS clock?
Are there additional configurations or diagnostics I should try on the Windows side?
Is there anything specific to the 192.168.0.x network that could be causing this issue?
I have been trying to resolve this for 1 month now and would greatly appreciate any help or insights. Thank you.
More Details :

Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise OS Version: 10.0.18362 N/A Build 18362 System Manufacturer: System Model: System Type: x64-based PC Processor(s): 1 Processor(s) Installed.
BIOS Version: American Megatrends Inc. 5.12, 05/03/2018
Time on Windows : 2024-08-19 23:22:13
Time on Ubuntu : Mon 19 Aug 2024 11:54:59 PM +08 (I set the time
to be few minutes behind the ubuntu to check if the synchronisation
is taking place)
Microsoft Windows : [Version 10.0.18362.356], last updated September 2019.
Enabled Windows Time Service debug logging.

w32tm /query /peers:
#Peers: 1
Peer: 192.168.0.100
State: Pending
Time Remaining: 0.0000000s
Mode: 0 (reserved)
Stratum: 0 (unspecified)
PeerPoll Interval: 0 (unspecified)
HostPoll Interval: 0 (unspecified)


You need to include the time on both systems. What is it? 2. Enable Windows Time Service debug logging. It works. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/active-directory/turn-on-debug-logging-in-windows-time-service 3. You need to include Windows version. 4. You need to include hardware details.


@GregAskew, sorry for the late reply. Here are the details:OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
OS Version:                10.0.18362 N/A Build 18362
System Manufacturer:
System Model:
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
BIOS Version:              American Megatrends Inc. 5.12, 05/03/2018
Time on Windows : 2024-08-19 23:22:13
Time on Ubuntu : Mon 19 Aug 2024 11:54:59 PM +08
( I had set the time to be few minutes behind the ubuntu)

Microsoft Windows : [Version 10.0.18362.356]
I have also enabled Windows Time Service debug logging.  Here are few sample messages :
154728 15:43:16.3551961s - W32TmServiceMain: ********** Time Slip Notification **********
PCT: 1442 154728 15:43:16.3552233s - ClockDispln TimeSlip: SetUnsync: LI:0 S:1 RDl:0 RDs:100000000 TSF:0x0
154728 15:43:16.3553097s - TimeProvCommand([NtpClient], TPC_TimeJumped) called.
154728 15:43:16.3553092s - ClockDispln: we're a reliable time service with no time source:

LS: 0, : 864000000000, WAIT: 86400000
154728 15:43:16.3553364s - UpdateTimerQueue1: TN:9877055310000::: LRT:9876935150000  LUT:9877055310000 LAFLTNS:0 TSLGT:0 LTNS:864000000000
154728 15:43:16.3553495s - W32TmServiceMain: waiting i16.000s (1024.000s)
154728 15:43:25.3499263s - NtpProvider: Created 0 sockets.
154728 15:43:25.3499584s - StartListeningThread completed!
154728 15:43:25.3499711s - PeerPollingThread: waiting forever
154728 15:43:25.3499927s - StartPeerPollingThread completed!
154728 15:43:25.3500029s - PeerPollingThread: PeerListUpdated

15:43:25.3500148s - UpdateTimerQueue1: TN:9877145150000::: LRT:9876935150000  LUT:9877055310000 LAFLTNS:0 TSLGT:0 LTNS:864000000000
5:43:25.3500708s - PeerPollingThread: waiting forever
15:43:25.3500842s - W32TmServiceMain: waiting i16.000s (1024.000s)
15:43:25.3501158s - W32TmServiceMain: RequestNetTopoChangeNotification Succeed
15:43:41.3503489s - W32TmServiceMain: timeout
15:43:41.3504186s - UpdateTimerQueue1: TN:9877305150000::: LRT:9876935150000  LUT:9877055310000 LAFLTNS:160002942 TSLGT:160002942 LTNS:864000000000
154728 15:43:41.3504378s - W32TmServiceMain: waiting 1024.000s

There still isn't enough information, however it is possible this may be a known defect in Windows that interferes with time synchronization. Specifically Windows attempts to use SSL data... note that one of the debug lines states that there is a large and abrupt time jump. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/active-directory/client-clock-reverts-to-previous-time

Also wouldn't hurt to update Windows, it was last updated five years ago on September 2019.

I have been trying with several time differences, going from 1 hour to as low as a few seconds, but the time sync is never successful. I am also monitoring the wireshark and there is some exchange between the two pcs during stripchart and /config /manualpeerlist etc but none during /resync. Do you think update is the only option? Anything other than these that I can try?

Update? What about the registry value in the article about the SSL time data?

I tried the steps : specifically reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config /v UtilizeSslTimeData /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
But the output is still the same.. No time data is available on w32tm /resync

Hi everyone, the problem is solved after I tried these two things:
updating the windows and delete NetTime from Control Panel. After this the sync was successful. Thank you all for your suggestions and kind help.
